# How to open the dropdown if a submenu is active?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Here if I click on the submenu I want to keep open the main menu dropdown. Now it doesn't keep open the main menu if I clicked on the submenu. After sub menu clicks it close the dropdown.

```
  <li><a href="#" class="hasSub" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1" aria-expanded="false">Main Menu</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list pl-3" id="menu1">
                        <li><a>sub menu1</a></li>
                        <li><a>sub menu 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

Comment: add your js code too, it will help us to understand the problem,

Comment: A snippet would be great as well

Answer (score 1):

```
let $active = $('nav .hasSub li.active');

if($active.length) {
  // or add your action
  $active.closest('.collapse').addClass('open');
}
```